# Insert R data.frame data into HIVE DB

Tags: r, hive

I have a data.frame with 1000-2000 records. I am using RJDBC to insert into HIVE and followed below steps but I am getting an error

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", classPath = list.files("C:/R 
Install/hive_lib",pattern="jar$",full.names=T),identifier.quote="'")
conn <- dbConnect(drv,  "servername", "username", "pwd")

dbWriteTable(conn, name = tablename, value = data.frame, row.names = FALSE)
```

**Error:**

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:334 mismatched input 'PRECISION' expecting ) near 'DOUBLE' in create table statement)
```

What is the best way to insert R data frame records into HIVE?